# Displaying IplImages in Qt labels

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, qt4

I ran into a routine that converts from IplImage to QImages in Qt, i tried it and it works perfects, after that i tried to display a video in a label using also Iplframes, it also worked, but now im trying to display live video from my webcam and im running into some kind of trouble because it doesnt display anything, Opencv 2.3 , Ubuntu Linux C++

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
//CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
while(1) { 

    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    cvWaitKey(33);
    if( !frame ) break;        
    cvCvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2RGB); 
    myImage = QImage((unsigned char *)frame->imageDataOrigin,frame->width,frame->height,QImage::Format_RGB888);
    myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
    myLabel.show();
    //sleep(1);
    Sleeper::msleep(33);
}
```

There i have the 2 options , capturefromcam or capturefromavi, from an avi video it converts and displays converted frames perfectly, but when i try the same thing for my webcam's captured frames it doesnt display anything, also i dont get any error or something like that, any idea?

Comment: can you output webcam data using imshow?

Comment: can you check if image is valid using isNull() ?

Comment: Im think that the problem might be in the converstion from IplImage to QImage, Im trying to find what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, `cvCaptureFromCAM()` failed to find a device at index `0`. But you don't know this because you are not coding defensively: `cvCaptureFromCAM()` returns `NULL` when it fails to access a device:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
if (!capture)
{
    // print error
    // quit application
}
```

Try passing `CV_CAP_ANY` or experiment with other indexes: 1, 2, 3, and if none of them work I suggest you check the [compatibility list](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS) and verify is your camera is supported by OpenCV.

The same attention should be payed with `cvQueryFrame()`:

```
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
if (!frame)
{
    // print error
    // quit application
}
```